# quickblox iOS simple chat error

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I'm integrating quickblox simple chat with my IOS application. I've added Quickblox framework and the pods folder. But i'm getting error for QB_NULLABLE and QB_NONNULL (Unknown data type). Please advice.

Comment: did you use cocoa pods to integrate the Quickblox framework or did you just drag and dropped the framework ??

Comment: I'm integrating quickblox simple chat with my IOS application. I've added Quickblox framework and the the pods folder. But i'm getting error for QB_NULLABLE and QB_NONNULL. Please advice

Comment: buddy thats what am asking have you added Quickblox framework by executing pod install ??? If you are drag and dropping quickblox  frameworks there is a hell lot of configurations that you have to make in project setting :) If you don't want to bother ur self with that (I believe you should never :p) simply install cocoa pods, add quickblox to your pod file and simply run pod install :)

Comment: Thanks @SandeepBhandari Let me try it will let you know

Comment: @Steverocks what's your Quickblox SDK version?

Comment: Hi @V.Guruquickblox we are  Using QuickBlox (2.9)  We used cocoa pods to install quickblox and try integrating the simple chat but getting the below error.

Comment: /Users/shrishtiinformatics/Desktop/Handychecks/Handychecks/Pods/QMServicesDevelopment/QMDBStorage/QMDBStorage/QMCDRecord/Categories/CoreData/Import/NSNumber+QMCDDataImport.h:9:12: Cannot find interface declaration for 'NSNumber'

Also we tried to run the simple-chat but getting the error below
/Users/shrishtiinformatics/Downloads/quickblox-ios-sdk-master/sample-chat/sample-chat/Pods/QMCVDevelopment/QMChatViewController/QMChatSection/QMChatSection.m:10:9: 'Quickblox/Quickblox.h' file not found

Comment: Also we tried to run the simple-chat but getting the error below
/Users/shrishtiinformatics/Downloads/quickblox-ios-sdk-master/sample-chat/sample-chat/Pods/QMCVDevelopment/QMChatViewController/QMChatSection/QMChatSection.m:10:9: 'Quickblox/Quickblox.h' file not found

Comment: @Steverocks, Could you please create issue on [github](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/new) and add as mush helpful information as you can.

Comment: Thanks @V.Guruquickblox will do that

Comment: Dear @V.Guruquickblox Please we have create the issue on github as instructed by you https://github.com/ramachandrantc/https---github.com-ramachandrantc-sample-chat/issues/1

Comment: Hi Dear @V.Guruquickblox Can you confirm if the above information on the Git is enough Regards Steve

Comment: @Steverocks Sorry for my late response. You should create an issue in our repo [here](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues)

Comment: yes @V.Guruquickblox i posted the issue here https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/726

Comment: Hi @SandeepBhandari  We Removed the manually added framework. but  Getting errors below

file:///Users/shrishtiinformatics/Desktop/Handychecks/Handychecks/CCResultViewController.xib: warning: Missing file: /Users/shrishtiinformatics/Desktop/Handychecks/Handychecks/CCResultViewController.xib is missing from working copy

Parse Issue Group
/Users/shrishtiinformatics/Desktop/Handychecks/Handychecks/Services/NotificationService.h:19:54: Expected a type